# I have this error delete_post() missing 1 required positional argument: 'id' when I click on the delete link

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I am trying to develop a function in django to delete a user's own post that he/she uploads to the website but I keep getting the following error. Can someone help me please? I am still relatively new to using Django[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8GWNL.png)

urls.py

```
path('delete-post/int:id/',views.delete_post,name='delete-post'),
```

views.py

```
def delete_post(request, id):
user = request.user.username
user = get_object_or_404(User, id=id)
if request.method == 'POST':
    user.delete()
    return redirect('home')
return render(request, 'index.html')
```

html

```
 <a href="delete-post/int:id/{{p_filter.id}}" class="flex items-center px-5 py-4 text-blue-500 hover:bg-lime-600 hover:text-red-500 rounded-md ">
                                       <i class="uil-trash-alt mr-1"></i>  delete
```

models.py

```
class DeletePost(models.Model): 
p_id=models.CharField(max_length=500)
username =models.CharField(max_length=100)
def __str__(self):
    return self.username
```

I would really appreciate a step by step explanation since my aim is to learn how to delete a post off a website. Thanks!

Comment: **Typo**: `'delete-post/int:id/'` should be`'delete-post/<int:id>/'` (Note the `<` and `>`). Also `"delete-post/int:id/{{p_filter.id}}"` is wrong and should be `"delete-post/{{p_filter.id}}/"` or better yet `"{% url 'delete-post' p_filter.id %}"`. Given that your request even reaches your view despite the mistake in the anchor tag `p_filter.id` also probably doesn't exist

Answer (score 0):

*Try this hope it will help you...*

***urls.py:***

```
path('delete-post<int:id>/',views.delete_post,name='delete-post'),
```

***views.py:***

```
def delete_post(request, id):
    DeletePost.objects.get(pk=id).delete()
        
    return redirect('home')
```

***html:***

```
<a href="{% url 'delete-post' id=p_filter.id %}" class="flex items-center px-5 py-4 text-blue-500 hover:bg-lime-600 hover:text-red-500 rounded-md ">
              <i class="uil-trash-alt mr-1"></i>  delete </a>
```

***Models.py:***

```
class DeletePost(models.Model): 
    p_id=models.CharField(max_length=500)
    username =models.CharField(max_length=100, related_name='UserOrderRelatedName')
    def __str__(self):
        return self.username
```